# C++0x legacy code problem

Tags: syntax, c++11, legacy-code

As all you know, C++0x can't bring lots of important changes because of legacy code: all legacy code (including C code) can be compilable with a C++0x compiler.

So why don't add something like `#pragma syntax(language_version)`, which will allow new syntax with breaking changes?

```
#include <legacy_code_header.h>

#pragma syntax(2098)

// something strange
func(x)
{
   return x + 1, x * 2;
}

int main()
{
   a, b = func(1.0);
   return a + b;
}
```

Comment: C++ are not meant to be a proper superset of C, it is never a design concern of C++ language designers to maintain 100% compatibility with C.

Answer (score 0):

Some C++0x compilers might allow this. After all, #pragmas are generally compiler specific and not dictated by the standard. Others support this with command line options.